# offshore vs. overseas

Tags: word-usage, meaning, meaning-in-context, word-choice, difference

I'm a little bit confused about these two words, as they have very similar meaning. Let's say I have a team in another country and I manage this team. Should I say:

> I manage an **offshore** team.

Or

> I manage an **overseas** team.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use either **offshore**/**offshoring** or **overseas**, depending on what you want to emphasize.

**Overseas** simply describes where the team members are located. It doesn't carry any connotation about the makeup of the team.

An **offshore** or **offshoring** team is often a team that's comprised of people who are not employees of your company. They might be contractors or employees of an outsourcing company that provides services to your company. Since the team members are located overseas and are not employees of your company, it suggests that it's more difficult and requires more skill to manage an offshore team.

Not every offshore team is made of non-employees. With "captive offshoring," a company creates a foreign subsidiary in an overseas location and the team members would be in the same company family as you. But it's less common because it's more complicated and therefore takes more time and costs more money than offshore outsourcing.

Answer (score 2):

In political terms and in your case:

> The registered overseas company refers to a company which registers in a place overseas and regards this place as one of its main markets at the same time. The registered offshore company refers to a company which registers in a offshore jurisdiction but does not operate in this jurisdiction. [Source](https://achibiz.com/guides/guide-for-offshore-and-overseas-corporate-services/)

[Other definitions](https://wikidiff.com/overseas/offshore):

> As adjectives the difference between overseas and offshore. is that overseas is abroad while offshore is moving away from the shore.

Mainly it means overseas is on different islands while offshore is just away from your island shore, not necessarily other islands and usually on sea.

So you should call your team an *overseas* team.

Answer (score 1):

As a native AmE speaker, my first thought when reading "I manage an offshore team" is that they work on an offshore oil platform or something--that the team operates *on the ocean*. "Overseas", on the other hand, makes it clear that what you mean is that they're in another country on another continent, but definitely on land.

I believe in some business circles "offshore" can be used to simply mean the same thing as "overseas", but it's not the association I would personally have for the word.

Answer (score 1):

Properly, "Overseas" means someplace separated from the speaker by an ocean. "Offshore" means on an island or a boat or an oil rig or something, away from the mainland.

Hungary is overseas (for me — I would have to cross the Atlantic Ocean to get there), but I wouldn't say Hungary is offshore. Hungary doesn't even *have* a shore.

In business, both words are sometimes extended to mean any foreign country, even if you could easily get there by land. Using "overseas" this way is familiar to me. Using "offshore" that way is unfamiliar to me, but the Oxford English Dictionary has citations from *Investors Chronicle* and *Financial Times*, so I guess it's a recognized usage in the UK. As an American, I'm not tempted.

Comment: Is Canada "overseas" to you, then? Cuba? Mexico?

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas no, maybe a little bit, no.